# How do the Promises work in this code?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a couple questions about the below code:

- `getRemoteProfile` returns `Promise.resolve` only for one condition but    `getRemoteProfile` calls are always chained with `then`, so what happens when that condition fails?
- What's the difference between `return promise` and `return
  promise.resolve`, I think `return promise.resolve` always fall into
  then

  ```
  function getRemoteProfile(id) {
      if (!id && /^_/.test(id)) {
          return Promise.resolve(null);
      }
      var isGroup = app.isGroupId(id);
      if (isGroup) {
          return getGroupInfo(id);
      } else {
          return getUserInfo(id.split('@')[0], app.currentUserDomain);
      }
  }

  function reloadProfile(id, keep) {
      return getRemoteProfile(id).then(function(contactProfile) {
          // var isGroup = app.isGroupId(id);
          if (contactProfile) {
              contactProfile.contact_id = id;
              if (!keep) {
                  delete profilePromises[id];
              }
              contactProfile.member = true;
              updateProfile(contactProfile.contact_id, contactProfile).then(function() {
                  app.imagesStorage.setContactIcon(contactProfile.contact_id);
              });

              return setDetails(contactProfile);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: I'd expect, that `getGroupInfo()` and `getUserInfo()` also return promises so that the function always returns a promise. Like `reloadProfile()` also always returns a promise even if it never calls `Promise.reolve()` itself; it returns a promise derived from the promise that `getRemoteProfile()` returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` cannot be called on objects that do not have `.then` properties. So, if `getRemoteProfile` ever returns something other than a `Promise`, an error will (almost always) be thrown.

But, in this case, if you don't have reason to suspect that the code is broken, I very much suspect that both `getGroupInfo` and `getUserInfo` construct and return Promises themselves. `getRemoteProfile` doesn't have to create one for them.

Generally, you use `Promise.resolve` in the case when a Promise is needed, but the current case doesn't require an actual asynchronous operation (such as a network request).

Comment: thanks, I checked and see getGroupInfo and getUserInfo also returns promise.

Answer (score 1):

> getRemoteProfile returns promise.resolve only for one condition but getRemoteProfile called with then, so what happens when not falls into condition

Presumably `getGroupInfo` and `getUserInfo` also return promises and the `getRemoteProfile` function will always go into one of these conditional branches that returns a value. All promises have a `.then` method so as long as the function always returns a promise, that should work.

> whats the difference between return promise and return prommise.resolve, I think return promise.resolve always fall into then

`Promise.resolve` creates a promise, so if you return `Promise.resolve(...)` then you `are` returning a promise.